# Forms and Strong Parameters Identification Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters, strong-parameters

I defined the following strong params and new method in a controller named FormsController. Use case is that the user can create one form which includes several fields.

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @forms = Form.all
  end

  def new
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
  end

  ...

  private
    def form_params
      params.require(:form).permit(:user, :name, :tag, :link, :repo, :hpx_id, :tmp_id)
    end
end
```

And currently use the following new view to get some inputs from user

```
<div class="form">
  <%= simple_form_for @param do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= render "hpx_select", name: "[form]hpx_id", selected: (params[:hpx_id]) %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inputs";>
      <%= f.input :user %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :tag %>
      <%= f.input :link %>
      <%= f.input :repo %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.select(:tmp_id, options_for_select(@forms.map{ |t| [t.name, t.id] })) %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I submit and create a new form, it inserts as :

```
SQL (6.4ms)  INSERT INTO "forms" ("user", "name", "tag", "link", "repo", "hpx_id", "tmp_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["user", "value1"], ["name", "value2"], ["tag", "value3"], ["link", "value4"], ["repo", "value5"], ["hpx_id", "id1"], ["tmp_id", "id2"], ["created_at", "2020-06-13 20:54:41.366047"], ["updated_at", "2020-06-13 20:54:41.366047"]]
```

The parameters hash, on submit, looks like :

```
{“user”=>”value1”, “name”=>”value2”, “tag”=>”value3”, “link”=>”value4”, “repo”=>”value5”, “hpx_id”=>”id1”, "tmp_id"=>”id2”}
```

I checked what name it is generating for a field inspecting element :

```
<input type="text" name="form[user]" id="form_user">
```

From now, is it possible to attribute any key or specific array of hashes to the form parameters to get output like :

```
form_params => { 1 => {user: "user1" }, 2 => {user: "user2" }, 3 => {user: "user3" }.. }
form_params => { 1 => {name: "name1" }, 2 => {name: "name2" }, 3 => {name: "name3" }.. }
...
```

And getting name as follow

```
<input type="text" name="form[1][user]" id="form_user">
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem, [it should look like this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

```
@form = Form.new(form_params)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I introduced this issue while writing the post because syntax was correct on my side. I edited the original post